# Utility of wrapping tensor in Variable with requires_grad=False in legacy PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I'm using a codebase that was written in 2017/18 and I found the following code:

```py
audio_norm = audio_norm.unsqueeze(0)
audio_norm = torch.autograd.Variable(audio_norm, requires_grad=False)
```

I am aware that wrapping tensors in `Variable` formerly allowed their gradients to be incorporated into the computation graph Torch builds for previous versions of Torch (now no longer needed) but I'm confused what the utility of wrapping a tensor in `torch.autograd.Variable(my_tensor, requires_grad=False)` would be.

Could someone explain if this was an idiom and what the analogous modern Torch code would be? My guess would be calling `detach` on the tensor to stop its gradients being tracked.

For reference, the relevant line from the codebase is [line 45 from the *data_utils.py* script of NVIDIA's Tacotron 2 implementation](https://github.com/NVIDIA/tacotron2/blob/185cd24e046cc1304b4f8e564734d2498c6e2e6f/data_utils.py#L45). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PyTorch 0.3.1 and earlier, any tensor involved in a computation that needed to be tracked by autograd had to be wrapped in a `Variable`. Semantically `Variable.requires_grad` in PyTorch 0.3.1 and earlier is equivalent to `Tensor.requires_grad` now. Basically, `requires_grad=False` simply tells autograd that you will never need the gradient w.r.t. that variable/tensor. Mathematical operations are only ever recorded (i.e. a computation graph is constructed) if at least one input variable/tensor has `requires_grad=True`.

Note that any code using PyTorch newer than 0.3.1 does not actually require the use of `Variable`, this includes the code in the repository you provided (which explicitly requires PyTorch >= 1.0). In 0.4 the functionality of `Variable` was merged into the `Tensor` class. In modern PyTorch, you simply have to set the `requires_grad` attribute of the tensor to achieve the same behavior. By default, a new user-defined tensor is already constructed with `requires_grad=False`, so the modern equivalent of the code you posted is usually to just delete the `Variable` line. If you aren't sure if the tensor already has `requires_grad == False` then you could explicitly set it.

```py
audio_norm = audio_norm.unsqueeze(0)
audio_norm.requires_grad_(False)
```

You can read the legacy documentation [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.3.1/notes/autograd.html#autograd-mechanics) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for

```
audio_norm = audio_norm.unsqueeze(0)
audio_norm = torch.tensor(audio_norm)
```

if you need it to require grad then

```
audio_norm = torch.tensor(audio_norm, require_grad=True)
```